# Encontrar todos los puntos en un radio determinado con Google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Tengo una lista de ~10000 lugares (latitud y longitud) y tengo un punto central (latitud y longitud). Quiero utilizando la API de Google map, encontrar todos los lugares (dentro de los 100000), que están a una distancia X (dada por mi) del centro dado.
Yo quiero creer que la API de google map te da esta información.

ACLARACION IMPORTANTE: Yo se que google map te dice la distancia entre 2 puntos, pero no quiero usar un ciclo que recorra las 10000 lugares chequeando distancia porque eso demoraría mucho tiempo.

Como resuelvo esto? Google map API no tiene una función que haga esto?

Comment: Hola, Christian. ¿Encontraste una manera de hacerlo? Tengo la misma inquietud. Gracias.

Comment: Intentaste hacerlo con GeoFire??